# 4.7.31 CiviVolunteer Issue

Tags: civivolunteer

After upgrading to 4.7.31 (On wordpress) - I have the following issue pop up - on pages, such as events that have CiviVolunteer fields.

```
Warning: Declaration of CRM_Volunteer_BAO_Project::copyValues(&$params) should be compatible with CRM_Core_DAO::copyValues(&$params, $serializeArrays = false) in /home5/site/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/org.civicrm.volunteer/CRM/Volunteer/BAO/Project.php on line 36
```

Line 36 has the following code:

```
class CRM_Volunteer_BAO_Project extends CRM_Volunteer_DAO_Project {
```

not sure what is wrong here. CiviVolunteer 4.7.21-2.2.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was [reported](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/VOL-316) recently, but I haven't had a moment to get into it. It should be a trivial fix, but you could also resolve this by turning down your PHP error reporting. See this [relevant](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) PHP [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors). It is inadvisable to run production sites with `display_errors` enabled.